# Convert a string with arithmetic operation to an interger in python

Tags: python

I have a question about how to convert strings with arithmetic operations like + or * from a string to an integer.

Here is my input and the error output:

```
    a = int('4*5')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4*5'
```

I've expected this operation saves the number 20 as an interger in variable a.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `eval`:

```
>>> a = eval('4 * 5')
>>> a
20
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
```

Caveat: *BE CAREFUL WITH THIS*. `eval()` will evaluate mathematical expressions like this one, but will also execute any valid python code it's given. For example,

```
>>> eval( 'type(a)' )
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: It Works :-) Thanks for helping and your advice

Answer (score 3):

It is evaluating the string as a whole as an integer without applying the mathematical operations present within the string, so obviously this fails, as `*` is not a valid digit.

There are certain ways to take code like this and evaluate it that can also  be dangerous, such as `eval`.  However, there is a library called [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) which has a much safer `eval` function:

[From the `pandas` documentation:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html)

> The following arithmetic operations are supported: +, -, *, /, **, %, // (python engine only) along with the following boolean operations: | (or), & (and), and ~ (not)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.eval('4*5')
20
```

This is a much safer alternative to using plain `eval`, which can run potentially malicious code on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* take the expression as a string, use Python's `eval` function.

```
a = eval('4*5')
a
> 20
```

Otherwise, just remove the quotes to make it an expression instead of a string:

```
a = 4*5
a
> 20
```

Comment: Then `int` is redundant ... Why is this upvoted ?

Comment: Question literally says "convert strings with arithmetic operations"

Comment: @scharette You're right. I usually like to edit as little as possible from the original question, but in this case it's unhelpful. Thanks!

Comment: @user3483203 I know it does, but I could also suggest`int(int(4*5))` following this logic...

Comment: @scharette, you can just do `int(eval('4 * 5'))` if you really want to make sure it returns an integer.

Comment: @JackMoody My comment is not valid anymore since he edited. My point was that saying to remove quotes and let the `int` cast was redundant.

Comment: In this special case I had to use the expression

Comment: @scharette it's still an excellent point; I find myself doing that a bit too much.

Comment: @scharette sorry if it was unclear, I wasn't replying to you, I was commenting on the answer

Comment: @user3483203 Oh, I see. That was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The dangerous way is to use the `eval` function.  `eval` is quite powerful, and often results in unexpected or unwanted behaviour from small errors in the input.

To do this properly, you need to process the string.  Extract each of the numerical strings and the operation.  Convert the strings to `int`s, then test the operation and apply the needed code.  For instance:

```
expr = '4*5'
num1 = int(expr[0])
num2 = int(expr[2])
op = expr[1]

if op == '*':
    result = num1 * num2
```

In general, Python language syntax (keywords, math symbols, punctuation, etc.) are not easily transferred between the program itself and the data you're using.